# ¿Cómo aumentar cada variable en 1?

Tags: java

Tengo que comprobar todas los posibles triángulos rectángulos **(x^2=y^2+z^2)** en números entre 500 y 1000, pero no logro hacer que el programa aumente en 1 en una variable y las demás queden fijas y que después de llegar al tope se cambie de variable.

```
public class TriangulosRectangulos {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    public TriangulosRectangulos (){
      x=5;
      y=4;
      z=3;
      }
      public void prueba(){
          while (x>=1000 && x<=500){introducir el código aquí
          if (Math.pow (x,2)==Math.pow(y,2)+Math.pow(z,2)){
           System.out.println("El siguiente triangulo es rectangulo 
          "+Math.pow(x,2)+"="+(Math.pow(y,2)+Math.pow(z,2)));
        }
      } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Nunca haces un incremento o decremento de *"x"* así que tu while nunca va terminar y siempre va a evaluar el mismo dato

Comment: Si, sé que no modifico la X de ninguna forma, al no saber como hacerlo preferí dejarlo simple y con la idea base

Comment: Creo que el problema no es el error, sino el conocimiento que tienes sobre programación. te recomiendo que vayas a [ask] para saber un poco más sobre preguntas bien y mal recibidas por la comunidad. También recomendarte que hagas un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio. Si bien podemos ayudarte con algunos errores particulares los usuarios no toman nada bien resolver tareas, no es la forma indicada de ayudar. Finalmente, citando el comentario de arriba: *"sé que no modifico la X de ninguna forma, al no saber como hacerlo..."* te recomiendo aprendas-repases fundamentos de programación

Comment: Tomaré muy en cuenta la sugerencia, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor si usas un `for` para poder controlar el `inicio` y el `limite` de entrada, tambien incluye ahi mismo el contador o si algun momento necesita puede tambien ser resta:

**for ( `variable inicial` ; `la condicion` ; `contador/restador` )**

Entonces para tu problema deberias hacer recorrido de las tres variable `x`, `y` y `z`

```
public void prueba() {
    int inicio = 500;
    int limite = 1000;

    System.out.println("La Formula del triangulo rectangulo: ( x^2  =  y^2  +  z^2 ) ");
    for (int x = inicio; x <= limite; x++) {
        for (int y = inicio; y <= limite; y++) {
            for (int z = inicio; z <= limite; z++) {
                if (Math.pow(x, 2) == Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2)) {
                    System.out.println("El siguiente triangulo es rectangulo (" +
                            x + "^2 = " + y + "^2 + " + z + "^2)");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si, tiene mucho más sentido, muchas gracias :)

Comment: @Javalearner si la respuesta te ayudo a resolver tu problema,  marcalo como respondida para otras personas que necesitarán esta ayuda :)